# Powershell remote-query for Server 2003's eventlog

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2003, event-log

Is there any way to remotely query the events on 2003 server thru Powershell. 
`Get-eventlog` doesn't have a `-credential` switch and `get-winevent` doesn't work on Server 2003.

I even tried the [impersonation module](http://poshcode.org/1867). It works with commands like `get-service`, `get-process`, `get-counter` but not with `get-wmiobject` or `get-eventlog`. Am I missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for this:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NTLogEvent -ComputerName $compName -Credential $cred
```

`gm` results of **Get-WmiObject** for **Win32_NTLogEvent** (yes, it can take a while to produce):

[image]

You can use for filtering (i.e. add `-filter "(TimeWritten>'$BeginDate')"` to gwmi command), don't forget to assign `$BeginDate` variable prior to that. See these:

- [get-wmiobject to pull logs using Win32_NTLogEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157169/get-wmiobject-to-pull-logs-using-win32-ntlogevent)
- [Early Filtering of Win32_NTLogEvent class](http://powershell.com/cs/forums/t/11585.aspx)

Comment: OK. This allows me to see the events of a 2003 server remotely. But it makes narrowing it down by `source`, `EventID` , `before` and `after`, much more difficult; isn't it. `TimeGenerated` needs to be converted and can't find what `EventID` is called. ISE hangs when I run `Get-WmiObject Win32_NTLogEvent | gm`

Comment: Is there no simple way to just add the `-Credential` switch to `Get-eventlog`.....That would be really great.

Comment: @AyanMullick: No, I don't think you can do that. Try this `-filter "(TimeWritten>'$BeginDate')"` See [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157169/get-wmiobject-to-pull-logs-using-win32-ntlogevent). You can also select [only the fields you need](http://powershell.com/cs/forums/t/11585.aspx) - may be slightly faster. I updated my answer with more information.

Comment: `Get-WinEvent -Path \\<Servername>\C$\winnt\system32\config\SysEvent.Evt  -Oldest`

Hi @Neolisk I am trying to read the `sysevnt.evt` file on the 2003 server with the `-Path` switch in `Get-WinEvent`. But I get an error.


`Get-WinEvent : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`

Is there any way around that?

Comment: @AyanMullick: I don't even know if it's supposed to work like this. The file could be locked by the OS. You can try pulling from shadow copy - see if you get better luck with that. Did my approach not work? Why did you unaccept?

Comment: I thought one couldn't further answer a question already answered. `Get-WmiObject Win32_NTLogEvent` worked but I thought `Get-WinEvent -Path` could be a better way simply because it'll make further queries much simpler; if only the `.evt` file wasn't locked by the OS. :(


Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Why does `select` accept wildcards but not `sourcename`

`Get-WmiObject -Query "select * from Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE (sourcename = '*kernel*')"`

Comment: @AyanMullick: You need to be using LIKE operator.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your Get-EventLog command within an Invoke-Command script block.

Comment: We can't enable PsRemoting on these production boxes.  :(

`Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". `

Comment: If you can get around the PSRemoting restrictions in place by your IT department, you should be good to go.

Comment: Absolutely @websch01ar; but getting approval for the environment [12,000 servers] will be a Herculean task. :)

Comment: Well I did say good luck!  lol.  I've had the same argument here, but I think we've gotten past that as the engineers are starting to appreciate the power of....PowerShell.